# Cannot add parameters to volley request

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I'm trying to change json parsing from HTTP connections to Volley, but I have problem with connections where I have to add parameters to connection. I know that normal connection works well and it connects with PHP file, but it says that I'm missing something which means that parameter is not sent or I have to change the way PHP read it. 
Android code for params looks like this :

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            url_get_comments, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    ....
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            pDialog.hide();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", tag + "");
            return params;
        }

    };
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```

PHP code for taking params looks like this :

```
if(isset($_GET['tag'])) {
```

The problem is that PHP doesn't see tag parameter.

Comment: You must use **POST** If you want to send any parameters with the request not **GET**. Change **GET** to **POST** and run it..

Comment: it works with post, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add params manually as key-value pair then send it with the GET method